# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors in ionic when adding navigation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this app I am building in Ionic and I tried adding navigation buttons from home page to both login and registration pages but when I add function `(click)=”loginPage()”` an error occured.

Below is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { RegisterPage } from '../pages/register/register';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    RegisterPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    RegisterPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { 

  }

  loginPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
  }

  registerPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
  }

}
```

**And home.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="home"> 
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 class="div-two">Welcome</ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row justify-content-start>
        <ion-col col-6 class="col">
          <div><button ion-button round (click)=”loginPage()”>Login</button></div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6 class="col">
          <div><button ion-button round (click)=”registerPage()”>Register</button></div>
        </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

I have tried all I could but still don't know what the cause of the error is. i am new to ionic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double quote charater is invalid. Do not use `”loginPage()”` but use `"loginPage()"`.

This sometimes happens when you copy some code to editor directly. Please be careful about that.